# Six seats at the table

Tags: prolog

I'd like to limit the number of people sitting at a table (6 to be precise) but with prolog I can't figure out how to do it

I have already tried to use `between (0, 5, W),`
but I don't understand why every time with the active trace I see that it advances with the increase of W but it fails to exit the next function

```
(W =: = 0 -> nb_setval (counter, 0), W is 5,
```

```
person(antonella).
person(domenico).
person(raffaella).
person(tommaso).
person(vincenzo).
person(azzurra).
person(cristiano).
person(francesca).
person(luigi).
person(giovanni).
person(marcella).
person(daniela).
person(nunzio).
person(leonardo).
person(silvia).
notinfamily(giovanni).
notinfamily(marcella).
notinfamily(daniela).
notinfamily(nunzio).
notinfamily(leonardo).
%declare fight
fight(giovanni, marcella).
fight(marcella, daniela).
fight(luigi, leonardo).
%declare the familys
family(antonella).
family(domenico).
family(raffaella).
family(tommaso).
family(vincenzo).

family1(azzurra).
family1(cristiano).
family1(francesca).
family1(luigi).

sitdown :-
    (   person(X);family(X)),
    \+ fight(X,_),
    \+ fight(_,X),
    between(0, 5, W),
    (   W =:= 0 -> nb_setval(counter,0), W is 5,
    writeln(W),
    nb_getval(counter,Countval),
    writeln(Countval)).
```

I expect the function to continue after the lf (which in prolog should be "->") but it always remains there without going ahead. I can insert what the Trace returns to me.

Comment: Start by how you model your data. The way you have it now is just a bit silly. Also, let go of all the `nb_*` stuff, you certainly don't need it. Finally, you might want to start by reading a tutorial or a textbook. You can try "Learn Prolog Now!" or "The Art of Prolog" (you can download the PDF for free on the book's website).

Comment: Ok thanks, I try to study from here and see if I get to the solution.

Comment: The only obvious representational issue I see here is the family stuff; I would instead say something like `family(antonella, a).` and `family(azzurra, b).` If you know the actual family names, use those, you could also number them there. You don't need to explicitly model `notinfamily/1`. But yes, `nb_setval` and friends are for extremely special circumstances, not this situation. You do need a way to keep track of who is and is not seated though.

Answer (score 1):

I have an incomplete solution. But I hope it is enough to give you some hope to figure out the rest. First I revisited your data model slightly:

```
family(antonella,1).
family(domenico,1).
family(raffaella,1).
family(tommaso,1).
family(vincenzo,1).

family(azzurra,2).
family(cristiano,2).
family(francesca,2).
family(luigi,2).
```

Also I removed `notinfamily/1` since you had one person who wasn't in a family or notinfamily and it cost me some debugging time. :) Better to infer it.

Next we need a couple helpers. First some helpers for your data model to make it easier to determine if families match or if people are fighting. These should be fairly straightforward to understand, I'm just ensuring that either the families actually match or one of them is not in a family (which we check with negation rather than `notinfamily/1`):

```
family_matches(P1, P2) :-
    family(P1, Family),
    family(P2, Family).
family_matches(P1, P2) :-
    \+ family(P1, _) ; \+ family(P2, _).
```

Fighting is not currently associative, so I made a separate predicate that is associative:

```
fighting(X, Y) :- fight(X, Y) ; fight(Y, X).
```

Initially I was using `select/3` which is really a nice way of plucking various items out of a list, but I realized doing different permutations was killing me, so I came up with this version that I can use to only generate combinations:

```
select_inorder(X, [X|Xs], Xs).
select_inorder(X, [_|Rem], Xs) :-
    select_inorder(X, Rem, Xs).
```

The use of this predicate will become clear in just a second.

I prefer not to get arithmetic involved in Prolog if I can avoid it. This seems at first blush like a case where you can just assume that there will be three tables of five and everything will be great. That turns out not to be true, but I thought I'd share the code I worked up anyway in case it helps you solve the problem. My plan was this: I'll have a predicate that knows it's assembling a list of five people. I'll initially turn your database into a list of people. I'll choose people from that list. When I have five, I'll verify that the table is valid. I'll have a main predicate that does the book keeping and runs this table generator three times.

```
seating([T1,T2,T3]) :-
    findall(X, person(X), People),
    make_table(People, T1, R1),
    make_table(R1, T2, R2),
    make_table(R2, T3, []).
```

This could probably be restated with DCG syntax more clearly. But that should look sensible to you. Making a table has a similar flavor:

```
make_table(People, [A,B,C,D,E], Unseated) :-
    select_inorder(A, People, P1),
    select_inorder(B, P1, P2),
    select_inorder(C, P2, P3),
    select_inorder(D, P3, P4),
    select_inorder(E, P4, Unseated),
    safe_table([A,B,C,D,E]).
```

`select_inorder/3` is used here to make sure that we choose people in order, since otherwise we're just wasting processing time. Once we have five people, we verify it. This is a classic "generate-test" loop.

```
safe_table(Table) :-
    forall((member(L, Table), member(R, Table)),
           (family_matches(L, R), \+ fighting(L, R))).
```

I kind of like the logical reading here. This is not super efficient, it's going to do a cross-product of all the items in the list. However, I think such a thing may be warranted since family_matches is not transitive (`family_matches(antonella, giovanni), family_matches(giovanni, azzurra)` is true but `family_matches(antonella, azzurra)` is not true).

Now of course, the bummer is that this does not work. But the reason it does not work is pretty simple: after we have placed all of family 1 at one table and all of family 2 at another table we have one person to move to their table and then we have to find a combination of five of the remaining people to sit together. But unfortunately, three of the people not in a family are fighting with each other. If you can make marcella and daniela get along, you'll get exactly one solution:

```
?- seating([T1,T2,T3]).
T1 = [antonella, domenico, raffaella, tommaso, vincenzo],
T2 = [azzurra, cristiano, francesca, luigi, giovanni],
T3 = [marcella, daniela, nunzio, leonardo, silvia] ;
false.
```

Making this work for incomplete tables sounds a bit tedious to me so I'm going to leave this where it is in the hopes it's still helpful to you somehow.

Comment: Thank you so much it is very useful to better understand how to solve the problem. One last question: how well should you know about prolog for doing this exercise for a two-hour exam?

Comment: @MicheleSpedalieri I don't know how to answer that question. This isn't a completely trivial problem. I would expect if you've been doing Prolog for a month or so, you might be able to do it. A few days of really intense study, I kind of doubt it, but you never know.